# Why won't this Java Jfreechart program run?

Tags: java, opengl, jfreechart, jogl

The following code was taken from: http://www.jzy3d.org/tutorial.php

```
package diag;

import org.jzy3d.chart.Chart;
import org.jzy3d.chart.ChartLauncher;
import org.jzy3d.colors.Color;
import org.jzy3d.colors.ColorMapper;
import org.jzy3d.colors.colormaps.ColorMapRainbow;
import org.jzy3d.maths.Coord3d;
import org.jzy3d.plot3d.primitives.MultiColorScatter;


public class charttt 
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int size = 100000;
        float x;
        float y;
        float z;
        Coord3d[] points = new Coord3d[size];

        // Create scatter points
        for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
            x = (float)Math.random() - 0.5f;
            y = (float)Math.random() - 0.5f;
            z = (float)Math.random() - 0.5f;
            points[i] = new Coord3d(x, y, z);
        }       

        // Create a drawable scatter with a colormap
        MultiColorScatter scatter = new MultiColorScatter( points, new ColorMapper( new ColorMapRainbow(), -0.5f, 0.5f ) );

        // Create a chart and add scatter
        Chart chart = new Chart();
        chart.getAxeLayout().setMainColor(Color.WHITE);
        chart.getView().setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        chart.getScene().add(scatter);
        ChartLauncher.openChart(chart);
    }
}
```

It compiles without any problems, but when I run it 
I get the following exception:

```
**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/media/opengl/GLCapabilitiesImmutable
    at diag.charttt.main(charttt.java:35)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.media.opengl.GLCapabilitiesImmutable
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more**
```

Any ideas as to what is going wrong?

Comment: The title is incorrect - the question is about Jzy3D, not JFreeChart.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have your jfreechart jar in your classpath while running the program as well. Something like:

```
java -classpath .;jfreechart.jar charttt
```

the name of the jar may be different, i just put 'jfreechart.jar' for the sake of example.

For understanding the error better, here is the reference from [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html):

> **NoClassDefFoundError**
>
> Thrown if the Java Virtual Machine or a ClassLoader instance tries to
>   load in the definition of a class (as part of a normal method call or
>   as part of creating a new instance using the new expression) and no
>   definition of the class could be found.